# Remove security question from Forms Based Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm building a small website which will have FBA enabled (SqlMembershipProvider) and I want signup to be as simple as possible, just a prompt for username (email address) and password.

How do I remove the security question from the create user control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I jumped the gun on that one.

It looks like the control will sense if the underlying provider required a question and answer. So, have you tried disabling it in the web.config?

> ```
> <add
>   name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
>   type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ..."
>   connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
>   enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
>   enablePasswordReset="true"
>   **requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"**
>   applicationName="/"
>   requiresUniqueEmail="false"
>   passwordFormat="Hashed"
>   maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
>   minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
>   minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
>   passwordAttemptWindow="10"
>   passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
> />
> ```

Wrong answer below:

---

Set the [QuestionAndAnswerRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.questionandanswerrequired.aspx) property to false.

Comment: and how do you propose the setting of a protected internal read-only property?

Comment: Edited my earlier non-answer.

Comment: the membership section is not present in my web.config, should I add it manually? if so, what is the right "connectionStringName" to use?

Answer (score 2):

Set requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" in your web.config

i.e.:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
            connectionStringName="LocalSQL" 
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
            requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
            passwordFormat="Hashed" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="15" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="5" 
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
            passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
            applicationName="/"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```